# How to Split string using * in java?

Tags: java, string

My String has contains multiple * but i want to split using * at of
the first index `~*{` of this regex but they have split all the sting
which contains *?

Here is the current code:

```
String text="hdr_Tran_Id=CRDSUMMARY~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*res_Status=00000~*{\"ResErrMsg\":\"SUCCESS\",\"ResTxnRefCode\":\"CARDNUMLIST\",\"ResLocalTxnDtTime\":\"20190830173112\",\"ResCardNumList\":[{\"ResCardNumber\":\"47703601****5004\",\"ResStatusDesc\":\"OPEN NORMAL\",\"ResCardStatus\":\"00\",\"ResEMailId\":\"lokesh.v4@gmail.com\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"16-11-1987\"},{\"ResCardNumber\":\"60820101****2002\",\"ResStatusDesc\":\"OPEN NORMAL\",\"ResCardStatus\":\"00\",\"ResEMailId\":\"bhandarkarn@gmail.com\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"01-01-1950\"}";




public static String validation(String text){
    System.out.println(text);
    String[] newText=null;
    String finalText=null;
    if (text.contains("~")) {
        newText=text.split("~*\\{");
        System.out.println("length "+newText.length);
        finalText=newText[1];
    System.out.println("New Text "+newText);
    System.out.println("Final  Text "+finalText);
    return finalText;
}
```

Comment: split will split at all of them. if you only want the first, use substring, or concatenate the later elements of the result of split

Comment: Pass a limit with [`String.split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-): `text.split("\\~\\*\\{", 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
newText=text.split("~*\\{", 2);
```

Check [String.split(java.lang.String regex, int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for reference